# Spotify play button generator not allowing selection light or dark options/Album cover?

Tags: spotify

When I use the spotify play button generator on spotifys developer section I cant choose Light or dark / Album cover. Only Large player or small... Is it something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The light/dark and list/cover options are only changeable for play buttons based on playlists. For artists, tracks and albums you can't change them.